# How to get EditorWindow client rect?

Tags: unity, gui, editors

I want to create a simple console-like custom [EditorWindow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) in Unity.
There is a bunch of lables (console lines).

I'm using [GUILayout.Begi/EndScrollView](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView.html) to position all the labels in one column.
The problem is that it places all the content inside the rectangle that matches label bounds, not EditowWindow bounds. As a result, I see weird placed scrollbars.

[image: EditorWindow]

I would be happy to recalculate ScrollView bounds, but can't find any clue in documentation how to make so.
Here is my code:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class MyEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    Vector2 scrollPosition = Vector2.zero;

    [MenuItem("Window/MyEditorWindow")]
    public static void ShowExample()
    {
        var wnd = GetWindow<MyEditorWindow>();
        wnd.titleContent = new GUIContent("MyEditorWindow");
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        scrollPosition = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition, GUILayout.Width(position.width), GUILayout.Height(position.height));

        var elapsed = new TimeSpan();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            elapsed = elapsed.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Some long long long long text");
        }

        GUI.EndScrollView();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way of making scrolbars which bound to the edges of the EditorWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I used `GUI.EndScrollView()`, not `GUILayout.EndScrollView()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't overwrite the width with your own value... :p

In my example I Use EditorGUILayout instead of GUILayout, but in this case that won't make a difference. The below code makes the scrollrect fill the entire window.

```
scrollPosition = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    GUILayout.Label("Some long long long long text");
}

EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
```

In case you want to get the actual width of the window, see EditorGUIUtility.[currentViewWidth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility-currentViewWidth.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's a good workaround, but the reason and fix was even simpler :)

Comment: True, I did miss the fact that you actually wrote GUI instead of GUILayout. But you still don't need to specify a width at all though